# AWS - How do I get prices from other merchants?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using Amazon Web Services (Product Advertising API) for my web application to search books on Amazon. So far I'm able to send a valid request and parse the XML response. My problem is I can't find the price for books like [this one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Lord-Rings-J-R-Tolkien/dp/0007610246/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1394018288&sr=1-1&keywords=0007610246). It seems that Amazon don't sell this item directly and some other merchants are responsible to do this. I couldn't find any Price for these items in the Response I've got from AWS. Where could I find it?

I'm using `Large` Response Group. Should I use other Response Groups?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Marketplace web service APIs](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_IfNew.html), and in particular the [Products API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_Overview.html). You can use the ASIN of a book to find the marketplace prices using the Products API.